# Need a jquery script to add totals of columns in a dynamically generated table and append row 'Totals'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a database driven table being generated in PHP, something like:

```
<table width=100% align=center id="countit" padding=1>
    <tr>
        <td><b>S. No.</b></td>
        <td><b>Election</b></td>
        <td><b>Graduates</b></td>
        <td><b>Professionals</b></td>
        <td><b>Doctorate</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Local</td>
        <td>52</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Municipal</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>765</td>
        <td>230</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
```

And so on. I was looking for a jQuery script that will calculate the totals of all columns that do not contain text data, and create a row called `Totals` that would be appended after the last row of the table. Any suggestions please? Please bear in mind that the table is dynamically generated, so I do not know total number of rows/columns.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and can you post that code?  If you've got nothing yet, you should look at the .each() ability in jQuery.  Also, as the table is dynamically generated, why don't you calculate the totals in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, not directly related to your question, but update your HTML as follows; it is best practise to use `<th>` tags for table headers:

```html
<table width=100% align=center id="countit" padding=1>
    <tr>
        <th>S. No.</th>
        <th>Election</th>
        <th>Graduates</th>
        <th>Professionals</th>
        <th>Doctorate</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Local</td>
        <td>52</td>
        <td>234</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Municipal</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>765</td>
        <td>230</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Secondly, add the following jQuery code to achieve what you are looking for:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var colIndex = 0;
  var html = '';
  var noOfColumns = $("#countit").find('tr')[0].cells.length;

  for (i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++) { 
    var total = 0;
    $("#countit tr").each(function(index) {
      
      var data = $(this).find('td').eq(colIndex).text();
      if (isInt(data)) {
        total=total+parseInt(data);
      }             
    });
    html+="<td>"+total+"</td>";      
    colIndex++;
  }
  $('#countit tr:last').after('<tr>'+html+'</tr>');

  function isInt(value) {
    return !isNaN(value) && 
         parseInt(Number(value)) == value && 
         !isNaN(parseInt(value, 10));
  }
});
```

Finally, you will need a reference to the jQuery library:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[See my example here...](http://jsfiddle.net/tn1x49jp/2/)

Comment: good code but OP is asking for a row at bottom of table and not a final column